# Rails Association Tertiary has_many belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm struggling to find the solution to this basic problem. Google terms would also be appreciated.

I have three tables: Shoes, Socks and Traits

A Shoe has many socks. Socks belongs to a Shoe. A sock has many traits. A trait belongs to a sock.

In my show view of Shoes, for a given shoe of id:x I want to display the socks that belong to it, and the traits that belong to those socks.

```
class ShoesController
  def show
    @shoe = Shoe.find(params[:id])
    @socks= @shoe.socks
  end
```

Using this code I can shoe the socks that belong to the shoe with id:x. But how do I find the traits that belong to the socks that belong to the shoe with id:x?
I think the solution is something like:

```
@sock = Sock________
@trait = @sock.traits
```

But I don't know how to run the search on this piece of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an array:

```
@traits = @socks.map(&:traits).flatten
```

To get an `ActiveRecord::Relation`:

```
@traits = Trait.where(sock: @socks)
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'm going to try it in the morning. Do you have any advice on what words I could have used to google it on my own? Or do you think it's more intuitively putting concepts together?

Comment: For the array solution, you just need to search 'ruby array' to get the ruby array help page http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html, and go over the methods to find the one that suits your need (after all socks is an array and you are trying to extract something from it). For the ActiveRecord::Relation, you need to go through the rails guides, so you know which one has the solution for an aspect of rails. In this case, it is the Active Record Query Interface guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html